# How do I plot a mle2 fit of a model in ggplot2, along with the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mle

I created a log likelihood function for the model, and use this with starting values in mle2() to fit the model (see blow), but can't figure out how to plot this model fit over top of the data in ggplot2. I've never posted on this site before, so I'm not sure where to put the data file, but I have one for reproducibility if needed.

I have spent days trying to find an example of specifically what I need to do, and can't find anything relevant. Apparently stat_smooth has most fitting options except mle, none of which I can use for this model. This is a fisheries Ricker stock-recruitment model which is fit with mle assuming log-normal errors.

LL function:

```
Ricker.LL <- function(a,b) {
  wf<-read.csv("wf_SR data.csv",sep=",",header=T)
  s <- wf$Adult.CPUE.t.1
  r <- wf$YOY.CPUE
  model.pred <- a*s*exp(-(b)*s)
  ndata <- length(s)
  NLL <- -sum(dlnorm(x=s,meanlog=model.pred,sdlog=1,log=TRUE))
  return(NLL)
}
```

mle2 fit:

```
mle2(minuslogl=Ricker.LL,start=list(a=0.4515,b=0.2665),method="Nelder-Mead",lower=-Inf,upper=Inf)
```

Then, I tried to assign predicted values to a new df in order to plot these with geom_line, but got the error:

```
dat <- predict(fit)

Error : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
Error in gfun(object, newdata = newdata, location = location, op = "predict") : 
  can only use predict() if formula specified
```

So, I tried to include the formula in mle2() before calling predict():

```
fit<-mle2(YOY.CPUE~a*Adult.CPUE.t.1*exp(-(b)*Adult.CPUE.t.1),data=wf,start=list(a=0.4515,b=0.2665))
```

and got the error: 'Error in '*' (x=c(....):operator needs one or two arguments.

I just want a plot of the data (s & r), with the associated fit overlain. I have had no problem using nls() and stat_smooth() but must use mle to fit this.

Comment: can you please give a little bit of data so we can have a [mcve] ?

Comment: PS you probably shouldn't be reading your data from a CSV file *inside* your log-likelihood function ...

Comment: Okay, like I said I don't see a file upload window, but here are some of the data:

Year YOY.CPUE Adult.CPUE.t.1
1980 1.236 2.2789
1981 2.225 3.4692
1982 0.865 2.9578
1983 1.795 1.8032
1984 0.178 3.7704
1985 0.132 1.5921
1986 0.249 1.3402
1987 0.043 0.3476
1988 0.044 0.5597
1989 0.319 0.7962
1990 0.095 0.4637
1991 0.045 1.0958
1992 0.194 0.9558
1993 0.383 1.254
1994 0.501 0.4157
1995 0.399 1.7198
1996 0.623 0.8677
1997 1.519 1.3774
1998 1.446 3.6541
1999 0.427 2.7101
2000 0.986 2.6237

Comment: I'm confused by your log-likelihood function.  You define `r` as YOY CPUE, but then you predict s (adult CPUE) as Ricker(s).  Did you mean YOY_CPUE ~ Ricker(adult_CPUE) ?  Also, the way you have this written, you'd get adult_CPUE ~ exp(Ricker(adult_CPUE)) ...

Comment: PS is that all of your data?  What coefficient estimates do you get with `nls()`?

Comment: No, that is the first 20 years, all I could fit in this text box. And I think you are misreading, 'model.pred' is r -- r (or YOY.CPUE) is on the left hand side of the equation. Now I'm confused, because IDK where you got adult_CPUE ~ exp(Ricker(adult_CPUE))

Comment: you have `-sum(dlnorm(x=s,meanlog=model.pred, ...)`, so `s` (adult CPUE is on the left side of the equation here).  When you put `meanlog=model.pred` in the equation, that means you expect the mean *on the log scale* to equal `model.pred` ...  can you post your full data set somewhere ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminaries:

```
library(bbmle)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
rickerfun <- function(x,a,b) {
    a*x*exp(-b*x)
}
```

There are a variety of ways to do this. The main difference in the predictions turns out to be whether we predict the *median* of the response distribution (equivalent to the geometric mean in the case of the log-Normal) or its mean ...

1. As a direct maximum likelihod estimate, with the log-mean equal to Ricker(A(t),a,b) [the `sdlog` parameter is estimated on the log scale; use lower bounds on `a` and `b` to avoid nuisance warning messages]

```
m1 <- mle2(YOY.CPUE ~ dlnorm(meanlog=log(rickerfun(Adult.CPUE.t.1,a,b)),
                         sdlog=exp(logsdlog)),
       method="L-BFGS-B",
       lower=c(a=1e-2,b=1e-2,logsdlog=-10),
       start=list(a=1,b=1,logsdlog=0),
       data=dat)
```

Also needed to get predictions from `mle2()`:

```
slnorm <- function(meanlog, sdlog) {
   list(title="Log-normal",
        median=exp(meanlog),
        mean=exp(meanlog+sdlog^2/2))
}
```

2. As a log-linear model (if `log(Y) = loga + log(A) - b*A`, exponentiating both sides shows `Y = a*A*exp(-b*A)`; Normal errors on the log scale correspond to log-Normal errors on the original scale)

```
 m2 <- lm(log(YOY.CPUE) ~ Adult.CPUE.t.1+ offset(log(Adult.CPUE.t.1)),
          data=dat)
```

3. As a generalized linear model with a log link and a Gamma response [the Gamma distribution has the same mean-variance relationship as the log-Normal, and is often an adequate approximation]

```
 m3 <- glm(YOY.CPUE ~ Adult.CPUE.t.1+ offset(log(Adult.CPUE.t.1)),
      data=dat,
      family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

4. For comparison, the `nls()` fit (this should also be equivalent to `m3` with `family=gaussian(link="log")`:

```
m4 <- nls(YOY.CPUE ~ a*Adult.CPUE.t.1*exp(-b*Adult.CPUE.t.1),
      start=list(a=0.45, b=0.27),
      data=dat)
```

Compute predictions for all models:

```
predframe <- data.frame(Adult.CPUE.t.1=seq(0,5.5,length=51))
predframe$mle2 <- predict(m1,newdata=predframe)
predframe$mle_med <- predict(m1,newdata=predframe,location="median")
predframe$loglm <- exp(predict(m2,newdata=predframe))
predframe$glm <- predict(m3,newdata=predframe,type="response")
predframe$nls <- predict(m4,newdata=predframe)
```

Melt for `ggplot` convenience:

```
predframe_m <- reshape2::melt(predframe,id.var="Adult.CPUE.t.1",
                              variable.name="model",
                              value.name="YOY.CPUE")
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(Adult.CPUE.t.1,YOY.CPUE))+ geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="glm",
                formula=y~x + offset(log(x)),
                method.args=list(family=Gamma(link="log")))+
    geom_point(data=predframe_m,aes(colour=model,shape=model))
```

[image]

Take-home messages:

- as stated above, the biggest difference in predictions is between predictions of the mean ("mle2") and of the median/geometric mean ("mle2_med" and "loglm"). The size of the difference surprised me: going from median to mean is equivalent to multiplying all predictions by `exp(sdlog^2/2)`
- the "mle2_med" and "loglm" predictions are identical (it's hard to see, but the green squares are exactly on top of the yellow triangles)
- the GLM prediction and the built-in `geom_smooth()` prediction are identical (they should be!)
- the coefficients of the mle2 and loglm models are identical, up to transformations:

```
all.equal(coef(m1)[["a"]],exp(coef(m2)[["(Intercept)"]]), tol=1e-5)
all.equal(coef(m1)[["b"]],-coef(m2)[["Adult.CPUE.t.1"]], tol=1e-4)
```

Comment: Wow, Ben thank you so much for your help. This is exactly the direction I was looking for! I altered the code to fit an alternate parameterization which considers age diversity (Shannon index of otolith age data for this species), and will attach that code & plot to a second answer so you can take a look if you're interested. Essentially trying to get at the idea that not all SSB contributes equally, similar to how people have incorporated a climate indicator (e.g., SST, NAO, etc.) in SR functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the model fit with age-diversity considered. I had to remove the lower bounds to get it to fit, and I get a 'longer object length not multiple of shorter object length' error, but it still seems to work. Thanks again for your help.

```
rickerH <- function(x,z,a,b,f) {
  a*x*exp(-b*x)*exp(f*z)
}

fit<-mle2(YOY.CPUE~dlnorm(meanlog=log(rickerH(Adult.CPUE.t.1,H.t.1,a,b,f)),
sdlog=exp(logsdlog)),
          # method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(a=0.01,b=0.01,f=0.01,logsdlog=-10),
          start=list(a=1,b=1,f=1,logsdlog=0),
          data=wf)
coef(fit)
slnorm <- function(meanlog,sdlog) {
  list(title="Log-normal",
       median=exp(meanlog),
       mean=exp(meanlog+sdlog^2/2))
}

# predframe <- data.frame(Adult.CPUE.t.1=seq(0,5.5,length=51))
predframe$mle2_f <- predict(fit,newdata=predframe)
# predframe$mle_med <- predict(fit,newdata=predframe,location="median")

predframe_melt <- reshape2::melt(predframe,id.var="Adult.CPUE.t.1",variable.name="model",
value.name="YOY.CPUE")

ggplot(wf,aes(Adult.CPUE.t.1,YOY.CPUE))+
  geom_point()+
  # geom_smooth(method="glm",formula=y~x+offset(log(x)),
method.args=list(family=Gamma(link="log")))+
  geom_line(data=predframe_melt,aes(color=model,shape=model),size=2)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: SR model w/ age diversity metric]