# How do I plot a mle2 fit from frair package in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mle

So I'm trying to plot a functional response curve in ggplot2, to do this I am using the frait_fit() and frair_boot() functions from the frair package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frair/frair.pdf).
So I call frair_fit:

```
FRAM18.fitII<- frair_fit(eaten~density, data=FRAM18, 
                       response="rogersII", 
                       start = list(a = 1, h = 0.1), 
                       fixed = list(T = 3))
```

and get this

```
> summary(FRAM18.fitII)
             Length Class  Mode     
call          6     -none- call     
x            56     -none- numeric  
y            56     -none- numeric  
response      1     -none- character
xvar          1     -none- character
yvar          1     -none- character
optimvars     2     -none- character
fixedvars     1     -none- character
coefficients  3     -none- numeric  
sample       56     -none- numeric  
fit           1     mle2   S4
```

And for frair_boot it looks like this:

```
FRAM18.bootII <- frair_boot(FRAM18.fitII, nboot=3000)
```

```
> summary(FRAM18.bootII)
             Length Class  Mode     
call              6 -none- call     
x                56 -none- numeric  
y                56 -none- numeric  
response          1 -none- character
xvar              1 -none- character
yvar              1 -none- character
optimvars         2 -none- character
fixedvars         1 -none- character
coefficients      3 -none- numeric  
bootcoefs      9000 -none- numeric  
sample       168000 -none- numeric  
n_failed          1 -none- numeric  
n_duplicated      1 -none- numeric  
n_boot            1 -none- numeric  
stratified        1 -none- logical  
fit              11 boot   list
```

I've tried using the predict and melt functions as outlined in this question [How do I plot a mle2 fit of a model in ggplot2, along with the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153916/how-do-i-plot-a-mle2-fit-of-a-model-in-ggplot2-along-with-the-data) only to get:

```
> FRAM18.fitII2$mle2 <- predict(FRAM18.fitII,newdata=FRAM18.fitII2)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('frfit', 'list')"
```

With similar results with the boot function output.

I can create a graph using

```
plot(FRAM18.fitII$x,FRAM18.fitII$y, pch=20, col='skyblue2', xlim=c(0,300))
lines(FRAM18.fitII, col='skyblue3')
```

but I'd like something more visually appealing.

The frair package tells me it uses mle2 to do its calculations so I'm wondering if there is a way to still get its output into ggplot2

My data looks like this:

| density | eaten |
| --- | --- |
| 180 | 40 |
| 180 | 4 |
| 160 | 70 |
| 180 | 55 |
| 100 | 13 |
| 50 | 16 |
| 25 | 4 |
| 15 | 15 |
| 140 | 46 |
| 160 | 22 |
| 25 | 25 |
| 50 | 0 |
| 25 | 18 |
| 160 | 11 |
| 100 | 6 |
| 50 | 50 |
| 100 | 75 |
| 15 | 9 |
| 15 | 15 |
| 140 | 138 |
| 140 | 140 |

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: my data looks like this: density eaten
180 40
180 4
160 70
180 55
100 13
50 16
25 4
15 15
140 46
180 22
25 25
50 0
25 18
160 11
100 6
50 50
100 75

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that information (e.g. as a code block)? In the meantime, see my answer ...

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work well. I'll try again! I'm trying out your answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load packages and data, do initial fit:

```r
library(frair)
library(emdbook)
data(ReedfrogFuncresp)
newfit <- frair_fit(Killed~Initial, data=ReedfrogFuncresp,
                    response="rogersII", 
                    start = list(a = 1, h = 0.1), 
                    fixed = list(T = 1))
```

Here's a `predict` method for the fitted model, which uses a bootstrap object (if provided) to construct confidence intervals:

```r
#' @param object fitted frair model
#' @param newdata specified densities for prediction; data frame
#' with density column name matching that of original model (\code{object$xvar})
#' @param boot output of \code{frair_boot}
#' @param quantiles for confidence intervals

predict.frfit <- function(object, newdata = NULL, boot = NULL, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975)) {
    fitfun <- get(object$response, pos = "package:frair")
    if (!is.null(newdata)) {
        newx <- newdata[[object$xvar]]
    } else {
        newx <- object$x
    }
    fitted <- fitfun(newx, as.list(object$coefficients))
    if (is.null(boot)) return(fitted)
    nms <- names(object$coefficients)
    bootvars <- boot$fit$t[,names(boot$fit$t0) %in% nms]
    colnames(bootvars) <- nms
    bootres <- apply(bootvars, 1,
                     function(b) fitfun(newx, as.list(b)))
    envelope <- t(apply(bootres, 1, quantile, quantiles))
    ret <- data.frame(fitted, envelope)
    names(ret) <- c(object$yvar, "lwr", "upr")
    return(ret)
}
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
pframe0 <- with(ReedfrogFuncresp,
               data.frame(Initial = seq(0, max(Initial), length = 101)))

## basic (predicted value only)
pframe <- data.frame(pframe0, Killed= predict(newfit, newdata=pframe0))

## with confidence intervals
b <- frair_boot(newfit, ncores=3, nboot=250)
pframe_b <- data.frame(pframe0, predict(newfit, newdata=pframe0, boot = b))

ggplot(ReedfrogFuncresp, aes(Initial, Killed)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(data = pframe_b) +
    geom_ribbon(data = pframe_b, aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr),
                colour = NA, alpha = 0.4)
```

[image: points and predicted values, CI ribbon]

Comment: In: pframe <- data.frame(pframe0, Killed= predict(newfit, newdata=pframe0)) 
Am I correct in understanding that "newfit" is the result of using predict.frfit?

Comment: no, `newfit` is the result of `frair_fit()` (see the beginning of my answer)

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry I'd screwed up something else in adjusting your code to my column names that lead me to assume I was using the wrong thing for newfit. It runs perfectly, thank you so much!!!

Comment: if this answer solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.