# How does the 'with' function work with glm model output?

Tags: r, vector, glm

I'm trying to understand the `with` function in context of a `glm` function output from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559593/how-to-fit-non-linear-function-to-data-in-ggplot2-using-maximum-likelihood-model)

First, a simple data set

```
set.seed(101)
x.test <- runif(50,2,8)
y.test <- 0.5^(x.test)
df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)
```

I want to fit the function of form `y.test ~ lambda/(1+ aii*x.test)` using the inverse link function in `glm`

```
g1 <- glm(y.test ~ x.test, family = gaussian(link = "inverse"))
coef(g1)
```

> (Intercept)        x.test 
> -10.884889    6.946893

```
s0 <- with(as.list(coef(g1)), 
      list(lambda = 1/`(Intercept)`, aii = x.test/`(Intercept)`))
```

This produces a single value for `$aii`: `[1] -0.6382144`

Why does the `with` function do that? Should `aii` not produce 50 values given that `x.test` is a vector containing 50 values?

Comment: No, `x.test` is a single value. Look at `coef(g1)`.

Comment: @Roland Ohh gotcha! I thought that s0 was evaluating x.test from the dataset for some reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing because `x.test` can be found in three different places:

- as a variable in the global workspace (a vector)
- as an element of `df` (a vector)
- as an element of `as.list(coef(g1))` (a single value giving the *coefficient* of `x.test` in the regression equation)

When `with(as.list(coef(g1)), ...)` is used, the third location is the one searched first.