# How to compute GLM for a model with two variables + fit to a log-likelihood function in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, log-likelihood

In an experiment, we had two types of treatments -- same species (x1.test at two densities 1000, 5000) or different species (x2.test at two densities 1000, 4000) for which we collected the total number of offspring (y.test) arranged as follows

```
set.seed(101)
x1.test <- c(1000,1000,5000,5000, NA,NA,NA,NA)
x2.test <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1000,1000,4000,4000)
y.test <- c(30,30,20,20,10,10,5,5)

df <- data.frame(x1.test, x2.test, y.test)
```

I want to fit my data to the following exponential function that can linearized as follows

> y.test = lambda * exp^ - aii x1.test - aij x2.test

> log(y.test) = log(lambda) + log (exp^ - aii x1.test - aij x2.test)

> log(y.test) = log(lambda)  - aii x1.test - aij x2.test

Therefore, the `glm` function is of the form

```
g1 <- glm(y.test ~ x1.test + x2.test, family = gaussian(link = "log"))

coef(g1)
```

It produces as `error in glm.fit(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0), weights = NULL, start = NULL,  : object 'fit' not found` presumable because there are NA's

Ultimately, I want to compute the estimates of lambda, aii, and aij as follows:

```
s0 <- with(as.list(coef(g1)), list(lambda = log(`(Intercept)`), aii = (x1.test * `(Intercept)`)),aij = (x2.test * `(Intercept)`))
```

Code modelled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560333/6820344)

Answer (score 1):

The toy dataset is:

```
> df
  x1.test x2.test y.test
1    1000      NA     30
2    1000      NA     30
3    5000      NA     20
4    5000      NA     20
5      NA    1000     10
6      NA    1000     10
7      NA    4000      5
8      NA    4000      5
```

Since there are no complete rows, it is not possible to fit a model with both `x1.test` and `x2.test` as predictors